# Returning same number of buckets everytime in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I am running the following query using Elasticsearch PHP client.

```
        $queryString = "";

                if ( !empty($ids)) {
                    $queryString  = "an.raw:".implode(" OR an.raw:", $ids);
                }

                $reportParams['index']  = "my_index";
                $reportParams['type']   = "my_type";
                $reportParams['size']   = 100000;

                $reportParams['body']['aggs'] = array(

                    "ans"=>array(
                        "terms"=>array(
                            "field"=>"an.raw",
                            "size"=>0
                        )
                    )
                );

                $reportParams['body']['query'] = array(
                    "filtered" => array(
                        "query" => array(
                            "query_string" => array(
                                "default_field" => "an",
                                "query" =>$queryString
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );

                $reportParams['body']['filter'] = array(
                    "range" => array(
                        "time" => array(
                            "gte" => $start,
                            "lte" => $end
                        )
                    )
                );

                $reportResponse = $this->client->search($reportParams);
```

I am running it inside a loop and everytime the query string and date will be different. But I am getting 45 buckets all the time. Is there any maximum limit which is set to 45 and it is limiting it ti 45 ? Or any mistake in the procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

You've set `size` to `0` hence you should get all applicable buckets. There is no such limit as 45 buckets. Try debugging your query by examining the key values of the term aggregation buckets.